# xDB Contact Switcher

Tags: xdb

Is there an option to switch Contact context programmatically?

Let's say i have some logic that depends on Contact context. When running such logic i would want to use something like

```
using (new Sitecore....ContactSwitcher("contactID"))
{
    //my logic with rules and personalization
}
```

I.e. Something EXM does with &recipient=xdb:{contactID} parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't exist a ContactSwitcher like LanguageSwitcher or UserSwitcher.

You need to identify new user when you want to switch to other contact.

```
            var contactIdentifier = "contactemail or otheridentifier"; 
            if (Tracker.Current.Contact != null && Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.Identifier == contactIdentifier)
            {
                // Contact already identified
                return;
            }
            Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(contactIdentifier);
```

If you want to switch back to previous user you need to identify again previous contact.